# Powershell change path of shortcuts in all folder and subfolder

Tags: powershell

can anyone please help me with my problem?
I want to change the path of shortchuts in all folders and subfolders because we have changed our server. That is why I need the code to loop through the all folders and subfolders.

The old path is defined as `oldPrefix` and the path as `newPrefix`, i have just put placeholders here.
The code currently only searches for shortcuts on desktop, I would need it to search through everything in desktop (so some kind of for loop maybe?).

```
$oldPrefix = "OLD SERVER"
$newPrefix = "NEW SERVER"
$searchPath = "$($env:USERPROFILE)\Desktop"

$shell = new-object -com wscript.shell
write-host "Updating shortcut target" -foregroundcolor red -backgroundcolor black

dir $searchPath -filter *.lnk -recurse | foreach {
$lnk = $shell.createShortcut( $_.fullname )
$oldPath= $lnk.targetPath
$lnkRegex = "^" + [regex]::escape( $oldPrefix )

if ( $oldPath -match $lnkRegex ) {
$newPath = $oldPath -replace $lnkRegex, $newPrefix

write-host "Found: " + $_.fullname -foregroundcolor yellow -backgroundcolor black
write-host " Replace: " + $oldPath
write-host " With: " + $newPath
$lnk.targetPath = $newPath
$lnk.Save()
}
}
```

thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!)

Answer (score 0):

If you change your dir row to this it will be recursive and get all *.lnk files in subdirectories too.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $searchPath -Filter *.lnk -Recurse | foreach {
```